# Merge [exim] and [exim4] tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

We don't have a lot questions tagged `exim`, but there's an arbitrary split between those tagged `exim` and `exim4`.

Can/Should these be merged?

Answer (score 1):

[exim4](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/exim4) should be a synonym of [exim](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/exim)

Need a mod to do it though...